# How could I modify a LinQ query on the fly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, asp.net-web-api2

I basically have a WebAPI service which is returning values to the client.

I've got a controller to handle the `documents` requests, which could be provided *parameterized* by a simple `enum`.

This simple enum is giving this kind of choices:

```
public enum DataRange
{
    Last7Days,
    Last30Days,
    Last90Days,
    ThisYear,
    Last10,
    Last50,
    Last100,
    Last500,
    All
}
```

I would like to modify the LinQ query "on the fly" before the query is actually processed by the DBContext, avoiding me creating a painful `switch` which duplicates code and it's not that easy-to-read, not even elegant.

I've actually "handled" the problem creating two different methods depending if it's a `Take(x)` involved or a `DateTime` `.Where()` filter, which makes me feel a little nervous.

In this method I return the `lambda` based on it's a `.Take(x)` like query involved:

```
private IQueryable<Documents> GetQueryByRegistries(DataRange dataRange)
{    
    switch (dataRange)
    {
        case DataRange.Last10:
            return Context.Documents
                              .Where(x => x.Auditoria)
                              .Include(x => x.Variables)
                              .Include(x => x.Events)
                              .OrderBy(x => x.Creation)
                              .Take(10);

        case DataRange.Last50:
            return Context.Documents
                              .Where(x => x.Auditoria)
                              .Include(x => x.Variables)
                              .Include(x => x.Events)
                              .OrderBy(x => x.Creation)
                              .Take(50);
                ...
        case DataRange.All:
            return Context.Documents
                              .Where(x.Auditoria)
                              .Include(x => x.Variables)
                              .Include(x => x.Events)
                              .OrderBy(x => x.Creation);

        default:
            return Context.Documents
                              .Where(x => x.Auditoria)
                            .Include(x => x.Variables)
                            .Include(x => x.Events)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Creation);
    }
}


private IOrderedQueryable<Documents> GetQueryByDays(DataRange dataRange)
{
    var limitDateTime = DataRange.GetClause(dataRange);
    var documents = Context.Documents
                              .Where(x => x.Auditoria
                                  && x.Creation >= limitDateTime)
                                     .Include(x => x.Variables)
                                     .Include(x => x.Events)
                                     .OrderBy(x => x.Creation);
    return documents;
}
```

Here I handle the creation of a DateTime for the `where` clause:

```
public static DateTime GetClause(DataRange dateTimeRange)
{
    switch (dateTimeRange)
    {
        case DataRange.Last7Days:
            return Last7Days();
        case DataRange.Last30Days:
            return Last30Days();
        case DataRange.Last90Days:
            return Last90Days();
        case DataRange.EsteAno:
            return ThisYear();
        default:
            return BigBang();
    }
}
```

Since I'm always trying to [avoid using switch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/29664/170427) scenarios, I would like to modify the `query` on the fly, avoiding to create this two big and ugly `switch`es and preventing me to parametrize the query itself, forcing to duplicate code.

I've given a try to [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) but I honestly don't really know how to apply my needs into it.

Thanks in advance and hope the examples help.

Comment: I can´t see anything common between those two methods. In particular I can´t see any `where`in the latter, nor where you make any switch upon if it is either a take-approach or a where-approach.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Hi! Thing is method was supposed to add the `Take` clause and another one just modify the `Where` clause

Comment: I liked the `return BigBang();` part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i understand is you want to change the query based on your enum. I think this is what you want.

```
private IQueryable<Documents> GetQueryByRegistries(DataRange dataRange)
{    
  // this is your base query. which will be common for all conditions.
  var query = Context.Documents
                          .Where(x => x.Auditoria)
                          .Include(x => x.Variables)
                          .Include(x => x.Events);

 switch (dataRange)
 {
    case DataRange.Last10:
        return query.Where(x => x.SomeId == 10).OrderBy(x => x.Creation)
                          .Take(10); // if you want to add Where again you can do that

    case DataRange.Last50:
        return query.OrderBy(x => x.Creation)
                          .Take(50);
            ...
    case DataRange.All:
        return query.OrderBy(x => x.Creation);

    default:
        return query.OrderBy(x => x.Creation);
  }
}
```